# Removing words from csv-file's line in python3

Tags: string, python-3.x, csv, line

How do you read a csv-file and remove a part from it, leaving the rest of the line intact?

If I have a line like this:

```
Chicago,0.6,5.5,1.3,11.1,NewYork,0.0
```

And my objective is to end up with this:

```
0.6,5.5,1.3,11.1,0.0
```

How should i do it? Is it possible to do it so that only numbers would be taken into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be very elegant solution, but you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

def isnumber(s):
    """Return True if it is a number, otherwise return False."""
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

df = pd.read_csv('/PATH/TO/FILE.csv', sep=',', header=None)
df = df[df.applymap(isnumber)].dropna(axis='columns')

df.to_csv('PATH/TO/OUTPUTFILE.csv', sep=',', header=None)
```

An important note: if you have more lines in your file, `dropna` will remove all columns with non-numbers.